# how to checked box checked always

Tags: android, checkbox

I have an contact list from which user select the contacts and send those contacts to other class,when user came back to activity selected contact remain selected,i compare the list from both the activity,and toast them,toast giving me the ans,but then also checkbox is not remained checked,what to do to made them checked always..

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.smscampaign;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
    import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

        ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    static  ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
        MyAdapter ma;
        Button send;
        String[] cellArray = null;
        int[] str;
        int v = 0;
        String  contacts;
        static int check1;
        ListView lv;
        int index;
        int top;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            setContentView(R.layout.get);
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);

            return true;

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addPage:

                break;

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(SmsSend.conct != null)
            {
             StringBuilder b= SmsSend.conct;
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // b3.append("");
            contacts = b.toString() ;

                cellArray = contacts.split(";"); //matching the phno with selected contacts came from activity a
                for(int i=0; i<cellArray.length;i++)
                { 
                    for(int j=0; j< phno1.size();j++){

                        if(cellArray[i].equals(phno1.get(j)) ){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cellArray[i] + "hii" +phno1.get(j), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                             ma.cb.setChecked(ma.mCheckStates.get(j, true));

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();

            System.out.println(ma.mCheckStates.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

            {
                if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {

                    phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                    checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                    ma.cb.setChecked( true);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                            + name1.get(i).toString());
                }

            }


            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ma.toggle(arg2);

        }

        public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

            Cursor phones = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                    null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String name = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                System.out.println(phoneNumber);

                name1.add(name);
                phno1.add(phoneNumber);

            }


            phones.close();


        }

        class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
                CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
            public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            TextView tv1, tv;
            CheckBox cb;

            MyAdapter() {
                mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            // Save ListView state

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return name1.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View vi = convertView;
                if (convertView == null)
                    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                tv.setText(name1.get(position));
                tv1.setText(phno1.get(position));
                cb.setTag(position);

                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                Collections.sort(name1);



                return vi;

            }






            public boolean isChecked(int position) {

                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

            }
        }

    }




SmsSend.java



    package com.example.smscampaign;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SmsSend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        BroadcastReceiver smsSentReciver, smsSentDelivery;
        EditText ed1, ed2;
        static int ResultCode = 12;
        static ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
        TextView txt;
    static  StringBuilder conct = new StringBuilder();
        String contacts = "";
        String delim = ";";
        public static String Name;
        TextView ed;
        int i=0;
        DataBaseHandler notasdb = new DataBaseHandler(this);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.smssend);

            ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            b3.setOnClickListener(this);
            b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            b4.setOnClickListener(this);
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum2);
             ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(smsSentReciver);
            unregisterReceiver(smsSentDelivery);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();

            smsSentReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms has been sent",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Fail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                    }
                }

            };
            smsSentDelivery = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms not Delivered",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            };
            registerReceiver(smsSentReciver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
            registerReceiver(smsSentDelivery, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button3:
                Name = ed1.getText().toString();


                Intent a = new Intent(SmsSend.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(a, ResultCode);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                Intent file = new Intent(SmsSend.this, File_Selecter.class);
                startActivity(file);
                break;

            case R.id.button1:

                break;

            case R.id.button2:

                Log.i("SMS", "Sendlist Size: " + sendlist.size());

                boolean diditwork1 = true;

                try {
                    String Name = ed1.getText().toString();

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    String msg = ed2.getText().toString();


                    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                            new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                            new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

                    Log.i("SMS", "contacts: " + contacts);

                    String[] cellArray;
                    // b3.append("");
                    contacts = conct.toString() ;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), contacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    cellArray = contacts.split(";");

                    for (int a1 = 0; a1 < cellArray.length; a1++) {

                        // smsManager.sendTextMessage(cellArray[a1].toString(),
                        // null,
                        // msg, piSend, piDelivered);
                    }
                    DataBaseHandler entry = new DataBaseHandler(SmsSend.this);
                    entry.open();
                    entry.entryCreate(Name, msg);

                    entry.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    diditwork1 = false;
                    String erroe = e.toString();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Dang it!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(erroe);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                } finally {
                    if (diditwork1) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Heck Yeah!");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Success");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                break;

            }

        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //Intent t = getIntent();  
                    sendlist = data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                    if (sendlist != null) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < sendlist.size(); i++) {
                            conct.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                            conct.append(delim);
                        }

                    }

                }



                i =  sendlist.size();
               txt.setText(Integer.toString(i));
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }

            }
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

set "android:checked="true" on your check box item

Comment: Then what will happen..??

Comment: check box is checked by default

Comment: but it is not working..,by default all the checkbox visible checked,but i want to checked only selected contacts to checked ,when user return back to the activity from another activity